# General Proof/Logic Question About a Limit

Tags: logic

Consider some sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$. Assume we want to show that it does not have a finite limit. Is this a valid proof technique:

Let L be any finite real number. Then proceed to show that the limit definition is not satisfied. But this proves that $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to that specific L. But since I let it be any L, does this prove what I wanted to show? Maybe if I said, for all L, and show the definition is not satisfied, so we can conclude there does not exist a limit L for the sequence, i.e. it is non-convergent.

I know there are other ways to prove non-convergence, I'm just wondering if this method is valid in general as an existence/non-existence argument. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if $L$ was chosen to be any arbitrary real number then showing $a_n$ doesn't converge to $L$ shows that $a_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: More generally, the way to prove that there is no real number with property $P$ (_e.g._ the property of being a limit of your sequence) is to say "Let $x$ be a real number...therefore $x$ does not have property $P$" where of course the "..." stands for a valid argument.

Comment: The main thing is that if you say it is any L, you cannot use a property of a specific L or your proof is good only for L's with that property.  It sounds obvious, but in a complicated situation you can get tangled up and assume something you did not mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid approach. If you show that every real number $L$ fails to be the limit of your sequence, it follows that the sequence does not have a limit.

In practice, it is easier to get the proof started by supposing that $L$ *is* the limit, and obtaining a contradiction. 
 Here is an example of such reasoning.

> Let $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+\dfrac{1}{x_n}$. Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ does not have a limit.

Sketch of Proof. Suppose $x_n\to L$. Then $x_{n+1}\to L$, hence $x_n+\dfrac{1}{x_n}\to L+\dfrac{1}{L}$. It follows that $L=L+\dfrac{1}{L}$, which is impossible.